# Confusion over $\sqrt{ x^2 } = |x|$ for simplifying expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

I know that when solving an equation such as

$\sqrt{ x^2 } = 9$, we must consider $\sqrt{ x^2 } = |x|$

thus $|x|=3$ so $x = 3$ or $-$$x=3$ hence $x = 3$ or $x = -3$

(Of course we usually just go straight to $x = 3$ or $x = -3$ directly.)

What happens, however, when we are simplifying $\sqrt{ x^2 }$ in an expression?

Supposed you are asked to show that an expression $\frac{m}{\sqrt{ x^2 }}$$x$ simplifies to just $m$.

In my notes, it simply goes like this:
$\frac{m}{\sqrt{ x^2 }}$$x$ = $\frac{m}{x}$$x$ = m

My question is this, where does $\sqrt{ x^2 } = |x|$ factor in? Conventionally, in simplifying expressions, as compared to solving equations, we seem to just leave out the need for there to be 2 possible solutions (note: no restriction was given at all, no involvement of real-world conditions like given $x > 0$ etc). Why is this so?

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of this! I have utilised this before - but doesn't this circumvent the original problem somehow? Suggesting that in some cases it doesn't apply?

Comment: It does , that is why i deleted the comment as i has misunderstood the question

Comment: @Charlz97 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it should be for $x\neq 0$

$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{ x^2 }}x = \frac{m}{|x|}x = sign(x)\cdot m=\begin{cases}m \quad x>0\\\\-m\quad x<0\end{cases}$$

depending upon the sign of $x$.

Comment: Actually, the actual question I'm currently doing involves integration - the part I surfaced was merely about simplification of the expression that was the integrand. So now..I need to integrate $m sign(x)$ - how do I do it?

Comment: @Charlz97 In this case you need to separate the integral in two parts, one for x>0 and ione for x<0.

Comment: And why do my notes ask me to just simplify it as such? Is it because I'm only at high school level? I've no idea what $sign(x)$ is.

Comment: @Charlz97 You need to assume m for x>0 and -m for x<0.

Comment: @Charlz97 $sign(x)$ is just a function which gives the sign of $x$, if $x\lt 0$ $sign(x) = -1$ , if $x\gt 0$, $sign(x) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x \ne 0$,$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{x^2}}x=m\frac{x}{|x|}=m\operatorname{sign}(x).$$

The statement that you wrote seems to already imply that $x>0$.

Comment: Actually, the actual question I'm currently doing involves integration - the part I surfaced was merely about simplification of the expression that was the integrand. So now..I need to integrate $m sign(x)$ - how do I do it?

Comment: And why do my notes ask me to just simplify it as such? Is it because I'm only at high school level? I've no idea what $sign(x)$ is.

Comment: @Charlz97 Even at high school level, using the wrong sign in some cases produces wrong results when these cases occur. We might be able to say more with more context

Comment: what is the region you have to integrate over? Because surely, if that area is strictly positive, the sign function will be 1 on the whole area and you can just integrate over $m$

Comment: $m$ is just a constant, the focus here I think is the sign of $x$. I agree with the rest that more context is needed. It could just be a careless mistake in the notes too.